# Yang-Mills Coulomb Gauge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, gauge-invariance

My Question is how to explicitly move into the "Coulomb gauge" in Yang-Mills theory.

Using the answer provided by QMechanic, one can move into the "temporal gauge" for Yang-Mills fields: [Gauge fixing choice for the gauge field $A_0$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33133/gauge-fixing-choice-for-the-gauge-field-a-0) .

Once in this gauge, to move into the "Coulomb gauge," does one take an explicitly *time independent* $g$, and demand that it satisfy:
$$
i\partial^\mu (g^{-1}(\partial_\mu - i A_{\mu})g) =  0
$$

Thus giving $\partial ^{\mu} A'_{\mu} = 0$?  Are we guaranteed that such a $g$ exists?  Thanks.

Comment: The Coulomb gauge is given by $\partial^i A_i$, where $i=1,2,3.$

Comment: @FredericBrünner sure, my last line would read $\partial^{\mu}A'_{\mu}=\partial^{i}A'_{i}=0$.  I'm wondering if my condition above is the condition required to fix the gauge.