# Does the temporal gauge condition uniquely determine a gauge in case of non-Abelian gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory, yang-mills, gauge

For a $U(1)$-gauge theory, we can fix $A_0 = 0$ by choosing a [temporal gauge](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=temporal+gauge).  Can we do the same for all of the gauge components of the $SU(2)$ gauge field, i.e.,  $W^a_0 = 0$ for $a \in \{1,2,3\}$?  Does this uniquely determine a gauge?

Comment: The question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33133 isn't a duplicate, but its answers contain the answer to at least the second part of your question, and implicitly to the first part, too.